# Orgmode Countdown Timer Seconds

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to specify seconds when starting the orgmode countdown timer? I've tried using fractions of a minute, such as 1.5, but it disregards anything after the first digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Org version 8.3* you can specify time as `hh:mm:ss`, letting
you enter, say, `:30` for 30 seconds.

* Specifically commit 93cc5fb (org-timer.el: hh:mm:ss format for
  setting a timer, 2015-06-02)